# Get GPS location from the web browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation

I am developing a mobile based web-site, there I have integrated Google Maps, I need to fill the 'From' field of Google Maps dynamically.

Is it possible to get the GPS location from web browser and fill it up in the 'From' field of a Google Map dynamically?

Comment: What mobiles do you intend to support?

Comment: i want to support all mobile browsers, but i-phone is the high priority

Comment: You might be better off writing a native app, as it'll allow tighter integration with the hardware, where it is available

Comment: if the need is only regarding location, then a native app is hugely overkill. iOS is not the only mobile, it just a priority.

Comment: https://github.com/onury/geolocator

Answer (score 206):

If you use the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation), it would be as simple as using the following code.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
  console.log(location.coords.latitude);
  console.log(location.coords.longitude);
  console.log(location.coords.accuracy);
});
```

You may also be able to use [Google's Client Location API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).

This issue has been discussed in [Is it possible to detect a mobile browser's GPS location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762141/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-mobile-browsers-gps-location) and [Get position data from mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97865/get-position-data-from-mobile-browser). You can find more information there.

Comment: Is the Google Client Location API mentioned still around? The link provided goes to Google Loader

Comment: I don't see it on that page as one of the available APIs. - You may be able to use to Google Latitude API: http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/ - With this it is possible to get the client's current location: http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/using_rest.html#RetrievingCurrent

Comment: For future readers, [the accuracy is measured in meters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6719542/2840103).

Comment: Hyy can we enable the sharing location autmatically via coding

Comment: Does this request the use of your location?

Comment: I believe it's good practive to wrap this around if (navigator.geolocation) {}
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location#browser_support

Answer (score 43):

See the discussion [How to get GPS coordinates in the browser](http://androidforums.com/g1-support/8868-how-get-gps-coordinates-browser.html)

There you have the link to example application [Where Am I?](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geolocate.html) that works on mobile devices. I've tested it on my Android and it started GPS module to get current coordinates. You can analyze the source on the living example.

I've made QR code for quick access from mobile:

[image: Where Am I QR code]

Comment: that QR saved me a whole bunch of effort

Comment: does not work on my Android phone even when GPS + WiFi is enabled and allowed.

Comment: The link _Where Am I?_ returns a 404 error.

Comment: QR code link broken.

Comment: @danubian Please include relevant information from the first link in this post, and delete the rest of the text as the links are broken.

Answer (score 21):

To give a bit more specific answer. HTML5 allows you to get the geo coordinates, and it does a pretty decent job. Overall the browser support for geolocation is pretty good, all major browsers except ie7 and ie8 (and opera mini). IE9 does the job but is the worst performer. Checkout caniuse.com:

[http://caniuse.com/#search=geol](http://caniuse.com/#search=geo)

Also you need the approval of your user to access their location, so make sure you check for this and give some decent instructions in case it's turned off. Especially for Iphone turning permissions on for Safari is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/782/html5-geolocation-aspnet-mvc-part1 is a handy reference for implementation in asp.net mvc environment

Answer (score 15):

Use this, and you will find all informations at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just a note: getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [GeoLocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), but browser support is rather thin on the ground at present. Most sites that care about such things use a GeoIP database (with the usual provisos about the inaccuracy of such a system). You could also look at third party services requiring user cooperation such as [FireEagle](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/developer).

Comment: thanks alot for your quick response.
if possible, can you provide me some more tips...

Answer (score 2):

Observable

```
/*
  function geo_success(position) {
    do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  }

  function geo_error() {
    alert("Sorry, no position available.");
  }

  var geo_options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge        : 30000,
    timeout           : 27000
  };

  var wpid = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
  */
  getLocation(): Observable<Position> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      const watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position: Position) => {
        observer.next(position);
      });
      return () => {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
      };
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the latest [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((loc) => {
  console.log('The location in lat lon format is: [', loc.coords.latitude, ',', loc.coords.longitude, ']');
})
```