# How is coords.accuracy measured, what unit is it in?

Tags: javascript, webkit

How is `coords.accuracy` measured, what unit is it in?

The goal is to use it to determine a radius of error when finding a location.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is typically expressed in meters.

The [Geolocation API specified by W3C](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) says:

> The accuracy attribute denotes the accuracy level of the latitude and
>   longitude coordinates. It is specified in meters and must be supported
>   by all implementations. The value of the accuracy attribute must be a
>   non-negative real number.

It's meters for PhoneGap, Google's various geo APIs, and so on.  It's almost certain that meters are the unit of measurement in whatever you're using.