# Automatic city finder

Tags: php, javascript, location

How do I print the membership form (in input) the city into the visitor?

> ```
>  Member Register Form
>  Name: Emre
>  Email:---
>  Pass:---
>  City: Istanbul  // Automatic location detection
> ```

Automatically detect the user's location (city), how to make?

*Sorry for bad English*

Comment: Try searching for the different Google APIs. There has been something called ClientLocation, but I think it was moved to one of the multiple geographic APIs: https://developers.google.com/loader/

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may send information about [the users current location (GPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577305/how-to-get-gps-location-from-the-web-browser). The user is then asked if he wants to share this information.

Based on another table (a [Geographical information system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system)) you can find out which town is at about that location (minimal distance). I guess the hardest task will be finding such a GIS for your region.

Another possibility is to get the approx. location through the IP adress, but this is very undetailed. I am usually assigned to positions about 100km away from my real place with such methods.