# Get GPS location using Javascript without Internet

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps

Hi Can we get GPS location using javascript without internet connection if device has GPS hardware?

**Please note who are marking it as duplicate**

I need javascript to work without internet connection and use GPS hardware to determine the location.

Comment: Are you using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation ? I've never really used it, especially offline, so I'm not sure how it works in different situations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577305/how-to-get-gps-location-from-the-web-browser

Comment: please note I want GPS location without internet connection using GPS hardware...

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can show you geolocation via `navigator.geolocation`.

```
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    else
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
}
function showPosition(position)
{
    console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
}
```

Comment: please note this works only if I have internet connection enabled. I wanted to see if it is possible to get GPS locaiton without internet if device has GPS hardware

Comment: @vinod8812 Are you 100% sure it doesn't work without internet?

Comment: yes..it just shows you the last cached location..

Comment: @vinod8812 Change the options used to not cache the location

Comment: This function doesn't works for offline mode. How to get the same in case of Offline mode?   I agree with @vinod8812.

Comment: Any word on this? Is it impossible offline? even with caching off and high accurac enabled?