# Pass google maps directions request/coordinates to phone navigation via website

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps api v3 web app and I'm curious if there's a way to pass the user's coordinates and the target location to a mobile users (iphone/android) Google Maps app so they can get real time directions if they link out to their maps app from the website?

I guess I don't know how I would make the coordinates available to the phone via the website with javascript?

site is here for reference: http://52.10.135.217/

Thanks you

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577305/how-to-get-gps-location-from-the-web-browser

Comment: Use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or [XMPP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) to communicate between the server and mobile to get the frequent updates.

Comment: Madhukar this is exactly what I needed thanks, the geolocation tip from 149 addressed the site but not the phone thanks