# JavaScript: Find nearby devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Is there a way to find nearby devices in a WebApp - either server or client side?

I thought about `JavaScript Bluetooth API`, but that would require the user to pair with the other device. Another thing I thought about is using the server to determine if the requests come from the same `IP/Area/...` but I don't know how accurate this would be.

Do you have any other ideas or feedback about my existing ideas?

Comment: I.P address can be easily spoofed, however Javascript on certain mobile devices can access location, however the end user has to allow this

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Geolocation API, it would be as simple as using the following code.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
  console.log(location.coords.latitude);
  console.log(location.coords.longitude);
  console.log(location.coords.accuracy);
});
```

You may also be able to use Google's Client Location API.

This issue has been discussed in Is it possible to detect a mobile browser's GPS location? and Get position data from mobile browser.

Took from: [Get GPS location from the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577305/get-gps-location-from-the-web-browser) (Added Credit)

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP address you can use some free web API, there are a lot of them. Here is an example using jQuery:

```js
$.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(data) {
    console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or another one, with additional info:

```js
$.get("https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/", function(data) {
  console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on client side using [Resonance Nearby](http://www.getresonance.net/). It works only if devices have microphones.